# How To add new Contact To existing Account?

Tags: apex, lightning, controller, aura, component

Created A component to Create a New Contact And Added it to Account Page layout. now i want to Connect That new contact to Account in which we have.

## Apex

```
public class CreateContact_Ctrl {
@AuraEnabled
    public static void getContact(string serverLastName,string serverEmail,string serverPhone){
     
            
        Contact con = new Contact();
        system.debug('value of lastName ==>' + serverLastName);
        system.debug('value of last Email ==>'+ serverEmail);
        system.debug('value of last Phone ==>'+ serverPhone);
        
        con.LastName = serverLastName ;
        con.Email = serverEmail ;
        con.Phone = serverPhone ;
        con.Department = 'Created Via Component';
            
        
         insert con;
    }
}
```

## Aura Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
                controller="CreateContact_Ctrl" access="global" >
   
    <aura:attribute name="lastname" type = "String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Email" type = "String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Phone" type = "String"/>
    
    
     <lightning:card footer="Click Save button to Create New Record" title="Create Contact">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="save" onclick="{!c.createContact}"/>
        </aura:set>
         
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">            
            <lightning:input name="input3" label="Enter LastName" placeholder="type here..." value="{!v.lastname}"/>
            <lightning:input name="input3" label="Enter Email" placeholder="type here..." value="{!v.Email}"/>
            <lightning:input name="input3" label="Enter Phone" placeholder="type here..." value="{!v.Phone}"/>
        </p>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

## Aura Controller

```
({
    createContact : function(component, event, helper) {
        //console.log('method Called');
        var clientLastName = component.get("v.lastname");
        var clientEmail = component.get("v.Email");
        var clientPhone = component.get("v.Phone");
        //var clientAccount = component.get("v.Account");
        
        //call Apex Class Method
        var action = component.get("c.getContact");
        
        //Pass parameter to apex Method (First Time).....
        action.setParams({
            "serverLastName":clientLastName,
            "serverEmail":clientEmail,
            "serverPhone":clientPhone    
        });
        
              
            //Placing the request to server to run it....
            $A.enqueueAction(action,false);
            action.setCallback(this,function(respons){
            var state = respons.getState();
            if(state=== "SUCCESS"){
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams(
            {
            title: 'info',
            message:'record Created Successfully !!!',
            duration:'200',
            key:'info_alt',
            type:'info',
            mode:'dismissible'
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
        }
            
        });
        
    }
})
```

Comment: can you narrow down what error you are getting? your questions is very broad and asking just how to develop something.

Comment: i want to add new Contact (which created by component) to Add in existing Account

Answer (score 0):

So you need to add the Account link to the new Contact.
To do that, use `recordId` param you have implicitly on your Aura Component

Aura component: add this near other `aura:attribute` rows

```html
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type = "String"/>
```

It will be prefilled automatically with Account Id
Then send this Id to the server (in JS controller):

```js
        action.setParams({
            "serverLastName":clientLastName,
            "serverEmail":clientEmail,
            "serverPhone":clientPhone,
            "serverAccountId":component.get("recordId")    
        });
```

Then use it in Apex

```java
    public static void getContact(string serverLastName,string serverEmail,string serverPhone, Id serverAccountId){
     
         // ...  leave the beginning of the method as is
        
        con.accountId =  serverAccountId;           
        insert con;
    }
```

Comment: Record Created As before but not Added To Existing Account

Comment: @mirzaKahekashan, can you add the `console.log` to see what goes into the params and check if the account Id is filled?